# Pythonnet: C# Code for passing in list with different types

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x

If I had the following list in python:

```
lst = [1,"string", 2.0]
```

What is the best practice for the C# function to accept this python list using pythonnet? Currently I am doing something like:

```
public static void func(object[] arr)
```

and manually casting the elements of the array to their respective datatypes. Obviously this is not ideal so I was wondering what the best practice for doing this would be.

Additionally, if I wanted to pass a python datetime object to a C# function, what would the C# method header look like?

Comment: whats the reason you say, "Obviously this is not ideal" (for casting objects to their respective types)?

Comment: Woops, coming from a python background, I'm not used to type restrictions on function parameters. Was wondering if there was any better way to do this without casting or making an object array.